# compiling tensoflow model using TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

During compilation of my model on tpu I run into error but using it on cpu it worsk just fine.This i how my data looks like

```
age           int64
sex           int64
cp            int64
trestbps      int64
chol          int64
fbs           int64
restecg       int64
thalach       int64
exang         int64
oldpeak     float64
slope         int64
ca            int64
thal         object
target        int64
dtype: object
```

```
target = df.pop('target')
```

```
numeric_feature_names = ['age', 'thalach', 'trestbps',  'chol', 'oldpeak']
numeric_features = df[numeric_feature_names]
tf.convert_to_tensor(numeric_features)
normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
normalizer.adapt(numeric_features)
```

```
def get_basic_model():
  
    return  tf.keras.Sequential([
    normalizer,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
  ])
```

```
with strategy.scope():
    model = get_basic_model()
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is the part where it  crashes with the following error

```
ValueError: Variable (<tf.Variable 'mean:0' shape=(5,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([ 54.594067 , 149.19473  , 131.78549  , 246.54785  ,   1.0577558],
      dtype=float32)>) was not created in the distribution strategy scope of (<tensorflow.python.distribute.tpu_strategy.TPUStrategyV2 object at 0x7f1e64e3f9d0>). It is most likely because some layers, model, or optimizer was being created outside the distribution strategy scope. Try to make sure your code looks similar to the following.
with strategy.scope():
  model=_create_model()
  model.compile(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the error,

> "It is most likely because some layers, model, or optimizer was being created outside the distribution strategy scope.Try to make sure your code looks similar to the following.
> with strategy.scope():
> model=_create_model()
> model.compile(...)
> "

The Normalization layer was created outside of the distribution strategy scope, thus the error. Please include that layer in the scope of the distribution strategy, as shown below.

```
def get_basic_model():

    normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
    normalizer.adapt(numeric_features)
    
    model=tf.keras.Sequential([
    normalizer,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])
    return  model

with strategy.scope():
    model = get_basic_model()
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```